# Are there rest calls for these Api Management actions?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Say I want to automate API Management, I would want to

1. Create Api (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apis#Apis_CreateOrUpdate)
2. Create certificate (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/certificates#Certificates_CreateOrUpdate)
3. Tie certificate to API (¿?)
4. Create API Policy (¿?)

I've went through [all the calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/) one by one, and wasn't able to identify anything meaningful.

edit: or a confirmation that this is not yet possible with the API.
edit: looking at the swagger definition of ApiManagement, I don't think its there?
edit: exported configuration to Git, doesn't look like it contains the cert, so this also wouldn't help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client Certificate is not represented in the model of the ApiContract. When you want to tie a Certificate to an API, we create a policy [authentication certificate policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-authentication-policies#ClientCertificate) in the API Scope.

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <base />
    <authentication-certificate thumbprint="***19B22E********5E2E**820" />
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base />
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
```

You can create an API Policy using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apimanagementrest/azure-api-management-rest-api-api-entity#SetAPIPolicy

Comment: ok, but what if I don't want to use old API? I mean, its pretty inconvenient to use 2 different authentication method to configure a single entity.

Comment: Then we have Powershell [Set API Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.apimanagement/v3.1.0/set-azurermapimanagementpolicy) and [Create API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.apimanagement/v3.1.0/new-azurermapimanagementapi). We also have nuget [API Management](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApiManagement)

Comment: The same old API in Direct access mode is also available via new Azure Resource Manager route(/subscriptions/{subId}/...).We have just not documented it.

Comment: with the same token?

Comment: for calling APIs through Azure Resource Manager you have to use **Bearer** Token Authorization. For calling the old API in Direct Access, you have to use **SharedAccessAuthorization**